# Python-Receiving MAC check failed when decrypting via RSA

Tags: python, encryption

Here is my code for generating the RSA keys:

```
def rsakeys():
 key = RSA.generate(4096)
 encrypted_key = key.export_key(pkcs=8, protection='scryptAndAES128-CBC')

 with open('privatekey.bin', 'wb') as keyfile:
    keyfile.write(encrypted_key)
    keyfile.close()
 with open('publickey.bin', 'wb') as keyfile:
    keyfile.write(key.publickey().export_key())
    keyfile.close()

 prepath = os.getenv('APPDATA')
 path = (prepath + '\\PythonApps')
 shutil.move('C:\\Python\\privatekey.bin', path)
 shutil.move('C:\\Python\\publickey.bin', path)
 return()
```

This function is to encrypt a file:

```
def encrypt():
 prepath = os.getenv('APPDATA')
 path = (prepath + '\\PythonApps')

 if not os.path.exists(path):
    print('Error: Must Have Valid RSA Keys')
 elif not os.path.isfile(path + '\\privatekey.bin'):
    print('Error: No Private RSA Key Generated')
 elif not os.path.isfile(path + '\\publickey.bin'):
    print('Error: No Public RSA Key Generated')
 else:
    with open('C:\\Python\\encrypted_data.txt', 'wb') as out_file:       
        file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:\\",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("text files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
        print(file)
        openfile = open(file, 'rb')
        read = openfile.read()
        print(read)

        recipient_key = RSA.import_key(open(path + '\\publickey.bin').read())
        session_key = get_random_bytes(16)
        cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key)
        enc_session_key = cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key)
        out_file.write(cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key))
        cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
        ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(read)
        out_file.write(enc_session_key)
        out_file.write(cipher_aes.nonce)
        out_file.write(tag)
        out_file.write(ciphertext)
        out_file.close()
        openfile.close()
        shutil.move('C:\\Python\\encrypted_data.txt', path + '\\encrypted_data.txt')
        print('Encryption Complete')
 return()
```

And this function is to decrypt data:

```
def decrypt():
 path = (os.getenv('APPDATA') + '\\PythonApps\\privatekey.bin')
 print(path)
 file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:\\",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("text files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
 with open(file, 'rb') as fobj:
    print('test')
    private_key = RSA.import_key(open(path).read())
    print('test2')
    enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = [fobj.read(x)
                                               for x in
                                               (private_key.size_in_bytes(),
                                                    16,16,-1)]
    cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
    session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)
    cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
    data = cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)
    print('test3')
    print(data)
    fobj.close()
return()
```

The traceback is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
C:\Users\bsmith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
\tkinter\__init__.py line 1702, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python\tkinterlogin.py", line 294, in decrypt
data = cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)
File "C:\Users\bsmith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\Cryptodome\Cipher\_mode_eax.py", line 341, in decrypt_and_verify
self.verify(received_mac_tag)
File "C:\Users\bsmith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\Cryptodome\Cipher\_mode_eax.py", line 293, in verify
raise ValueError("MAC check failed")
ValueError: MAC check failed
```

Everything works fine until I run the decryption function, at which point I hit MAC Check Failed. Previously, when I would use a passphrase with the encryption, I would receive RSA key format unsupported, so I switched, however, now I cannot figure out why it is receiving the current error. Any Ideas?

Comment: Which row and what's the actual traceback say? *(also, pet peeve, could you correct the indentation so that there's 4 spaces/1 tab in each block? Thank you)*

Comment: This is confusing as it looks like you write out the RSA-encrypted session key twice in succession. Is that intentional?

Comment: @JamesKPolk This is unintentional and fixed my issue. Thank you for pointing this out!